# Upvotes logic model (Parse)

Tags: android, parse-platform

Good afternoon,

I am creating a social app with posts. I would like to add an upvotes system to filter posts and retrieve your upvoted posts.

I took a look at Parse's AnyPic tutorial but I do not quite understand its system.

What would be the best way to manage upvotes in an app with Parse (what Parse classes and relations) ?

Thank you.